# Select all Table/View Names with each table Row Count in Teredata

Tags: sql, teradata, rowcount, tablename, dynamic-queries

I have been stuck into a question.
The question is I want to get all Table name with their Row Count from Teradata.

I have this query which gives me all View Name from a specific Schema.

I ]    `SELECT TableName FROM dbc.tables WHERE tablekind='V' AND databasename='SCHEMA' order by TableName;`

& I have this query which gives me row count for a specific Table/View in Schema.

II ]    `SELECT  COUNT(*) as RowsNum FROM SCHEMA.TABLE_NAME;`

Now can anyone tell me what to do to get the result from Query I `(TableName)` and put it into QUERY II `(TABLE_NAME)`
You help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Vrinda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a SP to collect row counts from all tables within a database, it's very basic, no error checking etc.

It shows a cursor and dynamic SQL using dbc.SysExecSQL or EXECUTE IMMEDIATE:

```
CREATE SET TABLE RowCounts
     (
      DatabaseName VARCHAR(30) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
      TableName VARCHAR(30) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
      RowCount BIGINT,
      COllectTimeStamp TIMESTAMP(2))
PRIMARY INDEX ( DatabaseName ,TableName )
;

REPLACE PROCEDURE GetRowCounts(IN DBName VARCHAR(30))
BEGIN
  DECLARE SqlTxt VARCHAR(500);
   FOR cur AS
      SELECT
         TRIM(DatabaseName) AS DBName,
         TRIM(TableName) AS TabName
      FROM dbc.Tables
      WHERE DatabaseName = :DBName
      AND TableKind = 'T'
   DO
     SET SqlTxt =
         'INSERT INTO RowCounts ' ||
         'SELECT ' ||
         '''' || cur.DBName || '''' || ',' ||
         '''' || cur.TabName || '''' || ',' ||
         'CAST(COUNT(*) AS BIGINT)' ||  ',' ||
         'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(2) ' ||
         'FROM ' || cur.DBName ||
         '.' || cur.TabName || ';';

     --CALL dbc.sysexecsql(:SqlTxt);
     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sqlTxt;
   END FOR;
END;
```

If you can't create a table or SP you might use a VOLATILE TABLE (as DrBailey suggested) and run the INSERTs returned by following query:

```
SELECT
   'INSERT INTO RowCounts ' ||
   'SELECT ' ||
   '''' || DatabaseName || '''' || ',' ||
   '''' || TableName || '''' || ',' ||
   'CAST(COUNT(*) AS BIGINT)' ||  ',' ||
   'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(2) ' ||
   'FROM ' || DatabaseName ||
   '.' || TableName || ';'
FROM dbc.tablesV 
WHERE tablekind='V' 
AND databasename='schema' 
ORDER BY TableName;
```

But a routine like this might already exist on your system, you might ask you DBA. If it dosn't have to be 100% accurate this info might also be extracted from collected statistics.

Comment: Hey Thanks for the response but I am not allowed to create a table, only select grant is available. :(

Comment: If you don't have the right to create a table you're probably also not allowed to create a SP :-(  Instead of a cursor you might create those INSERTs as a result set and then run them. Added this to my answer.

Comment: Hi again thanks for the help. Actually can you please tell me how to run all the inserts once they are inserted in the **RowCount** table. Actually the Query works fine and inserts all the `Insert Statement` in `RowCount` table but I don't know whats the next step i.e how to run all the inserts.

Comment: The query creates INSERT SELECT statments dynamically, you simply cut&paste the results of the query into your query window and execute them.

Comment: Thank you but I actually wanted this to be done in 1 or 2 queries because there are 100+ tables and I need to do this task daily every morning.

Comment: What are you going to do with those row ounts?  Talk to your DBA what you want to achieve and why.

Comment: Actually I have to do **Schema comparison** so I need Row counts to for comparing the tables in schemas.

Comment: If you have to run this task every morning you should talk to your DBA to setup  a process for that.

Comment: Okay I will do talk to the DBA but still I need some solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use dnoeth's answer but instead use create "create volatile table" this will use your spool to create the table and will delete all data when your session is closed. **You need no write access to use volatile tables.**

Answer (score 0):

Is there any way to find the row count of a table/view from system tables with out using count(*). Count(*) took ages to run for big tables. dbc.statsv view only include tables as we are not able to collect the stat of a view.